# IE 7 Windows Testing / Compatibility Mode

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

So, I've just gotten thrown off - I've began degrading a website in IE 7. I've inserted some IE 7 conditionals, and have toyed around with different ways going about it. (I've targeted specifically IE, IE7, IE8 and below.) **And have hit an issue where I've I noticed within my Windows IE 7 compatibility mode, that is the ONLY time when my conditionals are being recognized. When I turn off compatibility mode, the site renders broken.**

How can I determine how my site will look accross IE 7's??! Which will be read?

Comment: I don't understand. Can we see some code at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try using developer tools (F12)=> browser mode and changing it to IE7 instead of using compatibility mode?